# Laravel - Get records collection, if not exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to get all records from table IF these records not exists in another table, e.g.
**Table 'Cars'**

```
| ID | Name_of_car  
+----+----------------  
| 1 .| Toyota  
+----+----------------  
| 2 .| Ford
```

**Table 'Crashed_cars'**

```
| car_id | crash_date  
+--------+----------------  
| 1 .....| 22-02-2016
```

Now I want to get all not crashed cars - how can I do this?
At the moment I use a loop, but due to the number of entries (about 3000) I would have to use the direct collection. Here is my query:

```
Cars::select( 'id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'car', 'color' )->get();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is probably to get the ids of all crashed cars, and then searching for all other cars. In other words, something like this:

```
$crashedCarIds = CrashedCar::pluck('car_id')->all();
$cars = Car::whereNotIn('id', $crashedCarIds)->select(...)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the same result with one single query, which will increase the speed of your action.

One could use a **FULL OUTER JOIN** to achieve this, like this example from the following article:

```
select * from dbo.Students S FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Advisors A ON S.Advisor_ID=A.Advisor_ID where A.Advisor_ID is null
```

Article: http://www.datamartist.com/sql-inner-join-left-outer-join-full-outer-join-examples-with-syntax-for-sql-server no. 6.

Good luck!